# Why use Angular forwardRef in component provider?

Tags: angular, angular8

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  template: `<ng-content></ng-content>`,
  providers: [
    { provide: SourceComponent, useExisting: forwardRef(() => TargetComponent) }
  ]
})
export class TargetComponent extends SourceComponent implements OnInit {

}
```

This component uses `providers` property in decorator. But I could not understand tha aim of the `forwardRef()` in here. In [documentation](https://angular.io/api/core/forwardRef) says Allows to refer to references which are not yet defined. But if a reference is not definet it should throw exception.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So from the documentation for [forwardRef()](https://angular.io/api/core/forwardRef) it says.

> Allows to refer to references which are not yet defined.

It does basically what it says. It allows you to refer to a run-time reference before it has been defined.

Take the following example.

```js
const x = Example; 
// throws "Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'Example' before initialization"
const Example = "Hello";
```

In the above the variable `Example` is used before it is defined, and this triggers a run-time error.

We can fix this by using a function, because JavaScript parses scope at execution time.

```js
const x = () => Example;
const Example = "Hello";
console.log(x()); // prints "Hello"
```

The above prints `"Hello"` because JavaScript evaluates the function when it is executed and the variable `Example` exists in the stack frame that declared the function.

Now look at your example and see that `TargetComponent` is being referenced before it is declared, but we avoid an error by using a function.

```js
@Component({
  // ....
  providers: [
    { provide: SourceComponent, useExisting: forwardRef(() => TargetComponent) }
                                                           // ^^ not defined yet
  ]
})
export class TargetComponent extends SourceComponent implements OnInit {
          // ^^ declared here lower in source code
}
```

Comment: I would also look at the transpiled code where we can see that TargetComponent is defined before decorator. https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/AIYQ9gtgDmB2CmsAuAKA3gWAFAAIcHp8cA6U47PKAJzADcBLAE3ioGcAuHAbQrxzRzU6TeJwDKYAK5UAxvHDQ4iJABock1vACiAD3qsk9WAHNOAMzBUA7gEMqjAErwzKFAEocAXgB8OACp2xvBICjAIyB4Avrx8sXHxCYlJyXGEOAB66TiwYEg4zGZG8Iw4AJ7BvAC62JFu2PA6MFR5MgA2Nqys-oHBoUrIOA1IiIxdEtJyfeF59NCt8BDKXQDysACSsPR5mLhJaZn58G12xTgAFizwOK1gViw4RjisUrJXMmDMNUA

Comment: Great explanation, one more question why the need for forwardRef function? why this `useExisting: () => TargetComponent` not enough?

Comment: @robert Angular treats forwardRef specially and it will only unpack arrow function wrapped in forwardRef https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/3fb78aaaccf32b72a7b9eff55f144fb39e74474f/packages/compiler/src/util.ts#L207-L208

Comment: Is there any problem if I delete `providers` complately?